# How to syntax-highlight HTML inside <script id="template" type="text/ractive">?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ractivejs

Is there any Vs Code extension to syntax-highlight HTML inside ?

```
<script id="template" type="text/ractive"> <p>Hello, world!</p> </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

from this link I followed the same logic: https://forum.camunda.io/t/syntax-highlighting-for-cam-script-in-vsc/15218/2

so

1. locate the VSCode folder, mine is:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\html\syntaxes
```

2. open `html.tmLanguage.json`
3. search for `jscript` in the file
4. add `| ractive |` after `| jscript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  |`

should look like this:

```
| jscript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | ractive | livescript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  |
```

5. save the file
6. close vsvode and relaunch!!!

the result (image)
[the resulting hightlighting; not perfect but will do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm9k7.png)